# Creating a List<> Member with Spring Roo

Tags: java, spring-roo

The [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo) command `field set` creates a Set<> member.

> field set --fieldName --type

How does one go about creating a List<> instead?

Comment: I'm no longer prototyping with this technology and cant tell when I mark an answer as correct. Someone else will have to let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the latest relese(1.2.4) onwards roo supports lists.

```
field list --fieldname -- type
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your persistence implementation?  Are you using JPA or JDO?  Hibernate (JPA provider) will technically "support" lists but makes no guarantee as to the order returned (maintaining order in a database doesn't come for free) and so you may as well use a Set.

It's possible that Roo doesn't bother with lists under that reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

I just change it in the java code from set to list. If the roo console is open, It updates automatically .aj files. It just works.