# Spring Roo - MongoDb -- List of String

Tags: list, mongodb, spring-roo

[Creating a List<> Member with Spring Roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222552/creating-a-list-member-with-spring-roo)
that does not answer my question!

So what I want to do is "field list --fieldName addressList"
but the Spring roo seems only allow "field set --fieldName addressList --type ~.model.A" and I can't even do " field set --fieldName addressList --type java.lang.String"

so it should be very simple but how come it doesn't support that? or what should I be doing instead to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 0):

"how come it doesn't support that?"

Because this part of the framework is designed to represent the relationships of persisted entities.  Why would you want to relate to a (non-set) list?  How would you know if the entry was part of a related record and not just a duplicate?

"and I can't even do " field set --fieldName addressList --type java.lang.String""

That's because java.lang.String isn't a jpa class.  You can only relate jpa entities to each other.

You should create an Address class with a String field representation that you relate to this object.

```
entity jpa --class ~.Address
field string AddressLine1 --notNull
field string AddressLine2 
focus --class ~.YourClassThatNeedsAnAddressList
field set --fieldName addressList --type ~.Address
```

Now each instance of ~.YourClassThatNeedsAnAddressList can have multiple addresses associated to it.  Each address is made up of two strings.

Comment: thanks, it seems that I need to create some unnecessary classes. what about if I want to store a list of string IDs? in document on mongodb?

Comment: Seems like you aren't thinking object orientation.  What would a list of strings represent?  What would the ID represent?  What would the ID be able to do? (to itself?)  I have come to the conclusion that a list of anything has associated functionality - I challenge someone to find an example that doesn't.  That being the case, you should model not only the class that the list contains, but also model the list itself as a class.   This means that instead of creating a field list, you would create a field --fieldName addresses --Type ~.Addresses. Addresses could then be anything - map,set,list.